# MYSQL query error

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

What is wrong with the syntax or query?

```
SET @q=1000;
SET @p=5.00;

SELECT @ccount := COUNT(*) FROM 1detail WHERE price>=@p;
if(@ccount='0') THEN 
INSERT INTO 1detail (price,quantity) VALUES (@p,@q); 

ELSE

INSERT INTO 2detail (price,quantity) VALUES (@p,@q);  
END IF;
```

It gives me the error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if(@ccount='0') THEN 
>   INSERT INTO 1detail (price,quantity) VALUES (@p,@q)' at line 1:

To create table (that is working):

```
CREATE TABLE 1detail 
(
quantity int, 
price DECIMAL(15,2) 
);

CREATE TABLE 2detail 
(
quantity int, 
price DECIMAL(15,2) 
);


INSERT INTO 1detail
(quantity, price)
VALUES
('5', '10');
```

Comment: Is this code inside a function or procedure or trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table names that start with digits need to be escaped.  And, `if` is only used inside functions, stored procedures, and triggers.  Assuming this code is "if"-safe:

```
SET @q=1000;
SET @p=5.00;

SELECT @ccount := COUNT(*) FROM `1detail` WHERE price>=@p;
if(@ccount='0') THEN 
INSERT INTO `1detail`(price,quantity) VALUES (@p,@q); 
ELSE
INSERT INTO `2detail`(price,quantity) VALUES (@p,@q);  
END IF;
```

If not, you can just do this as two inserts:

```
INSERT INTO `2detail`(price,quantity)
    VALUES (@p, @q)
    WHERE exists (select 1 from `detail` where price >= @p)

INSERT INTO `1detail`(price,quantity)
    VALUES (@p, @q)
    WHERE not exists (select 1 from `detail` where price >= @p)
```